# i want codepen to angular component for this template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, navbar, codepen

i want to use this in angular component i tried alot of diffeent method already but got confused even more someone give simple solution please.

```js
    var app = function () {
        var body = undefined;
        var menu = undefined;
        var menuItems = undefined;
        var init = function init() {
            body = document.querySelector('body');
            menu = document.querySelector('.menu-icon');
            menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__list-item');
            applyListeners();
        };
        var applyListeners = function applyListeners() {
            menu.addEventListener('click', function () {
                return toggleClass(body, 'nav-active');
            });
        };
        var toggleClass = function toggleClass(element, stringClass) {
            if (element.classList.contains(stringClass)) element.classList.remove(stringClass);else element.classList.add(stringClass);
        };
        init();
    }();
```

```css
/* Please ❤ this if you like it! */


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i');

body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #c4c3ca;
    background-color: black;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* #Primary style
================================================== */

.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.over-hide{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.full-height {
    height: 100vh;
}

/* #Navigation
================================================== */
 
.cd-header{
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
} 
.header-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    margin-left: 50px;
} 
.logo-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    top: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.logo-wrap a {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    transition : all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.logo-wrap a span{ 
    color: #8167a9;
}
.logo-wrap a:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.nav-but-wrap{ 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    transition : all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.menu-icon {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
.menu-icon__line {
    height: 2px;
    width: 30px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
    transition: background-color .5s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
    transition: transform .2s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    transition: transform .2s ease, background-color .5s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
}
.menu-icon__line-left {
    width: 16.5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.menu-icon__line-right {
    width: 16.5px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon__line-left,
.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon__line-right {
    width: 30px;
}
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 98;
}
.nav:before, .nav:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(20, 21, 26,0.6);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 200%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.6s, border-radius linear 0.8s;
    transition: -webkit-transform cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.6s, border-radius linear 0.8s;
    transition: transform cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.6s, border-radius linear 0.8s;
    transition: transform cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.6s, -webkit-transform cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.6s, border-radius linear 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateX(100%) translateY(-100%);
}
.nav:after {
    background: rgba(9,9,12,1);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
.nav:before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
          transition-delay: .2s;
}
.nav__content {
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
          transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav__list {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.nav__list-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;
          transition-delay: 0.8s;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden; 
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 8vh;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1.15;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0%);
          transform: translate(100px, 0%);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .2s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .2s ease, transform .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .2s ease, transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav__list-item a{ 
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    overflow: hidden; 
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-weight: 900;
    z-index: 2;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear; 
}
.nav__list-item a:after{ 
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #8167a9;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear; 
}
.nav__list-item a:hover:after{ 
    height: 4px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav__list-item a:hover{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.nav__list-item.active-nav a{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.nav__list-item.active-nav a:after{ 
    height: 4px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
body.nav-active .nav__content {
    visibility: visible;
}
body.nav-active .menu-icon__line {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-45deg);
}
body.nav-active .menu-icon__line-left {
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 4px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translate(2px, 4px) rotate(45deg);
}
body.nav-active .menu-icon__line-right {
    width: 15px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, -3.5px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translate(-3px, -3.5px) rotate(45deg);
}
body.nav-active .menu-icon:hover .menu-icon__line-left,
body.nav-active .menu-icon:hover .menu-icon__line-right {
    width: 15px;
}
body.nav-active .nav {
    visibility: visible;
}
body.nav-active .nav:before, body.nav-active .nav:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
          transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
    border-radius: 0;
}
body.nav-active .nav:after {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .1s;
          transition-delay: .1s;
}
body.nav-active .nav:before {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
          transform: translateX(0%);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, color .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease, color .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease, transform .3s ease, color .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease, transform .3s ease, color .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(0) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.7s;
          transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;
          transition-delay: 0.8s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.9s;
          transition-delay: 0.9s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
          transition-delay: 1s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.1s;
          transition-delay: 1.1s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.2s;
          transition-delay: 1.2s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.3s;
          transition-delay: 1.3s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.4s;
          transition-delay: 1.4s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.5s;
          transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(9) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.6s;
          transition-delay: 1.6s;
}
body.nav-active .nav__list-item:nth-child(10) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.7s;
          transition-delay: 1.7s;
}
```

```html
    <header class="cd-header">
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrap">
                <a href="#" class="hover-target"><span>your</span>logo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-but-wrap">
                <div class="menu-icon hover-target">
                    <span class="menu-icon__line menu-icon__line-left"></span>
                    <span class="menu-icon__line"></span>
                    <span class="menu-icon__line menu-icon__line-right"></span>
                </div>                  
            </div>                  
        </div>              
    </header>

    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav__content">
            <ul class="nav__list">
                <li class="nav__list-item active-nav"><a href="#" class="hover-target">home</a></li>
                <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="#" class="hover-target">studio</a></li>
                <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="#" class="hover-target">news</a></li>
                <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="#" class="hover-target">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for telling me about images and codes

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking us to rewrite this JS into Angular for you?

Comment: i already created my own version but the animation for css not working the navbar is appearing but i have turb navlist opacit to 1 to see it othervise css coordination with typescript is not working